# Is there any benefits of using generic parameter rather than using the base class parameter?

Tags: java

Please review the code below:

```
abstract class Shape {

    protected double x;
    protected double y;

    public Shape(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    abstract protected void draw();
}

class Circle extends Shape {

    public Circle(double x, double y, double r) {
        super(x, y);
        this.r = r;
    }

    protected double r;

    protected void draw() {
        System.out.println(String.format("Draw Circle. %f %f %f", x, y ,r));
    }
}

class RenderEngine {
    public static void draw1(Shape s) {
        s.draw();
    }

    public static <T extends Shape> void draw2(T t) {
        t.draw();
    }
}

public class Runner {

    @Test
    public void run() {
        Circle c = new Circle(1,2,3);
        RenderEngine.draw1(c);
        RenderEngine.draw2(c);
    }
}
```

What's the difference between draw1() and draw2()? Which one is better? Does draw2() have more extensibility? Or does draw2() have better performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference in your scenario, because the type of the object being drawn is consumed internally in the `drawX` method.

It would make a difference if your method were to use `T` in some other context, such as returning the original back to the caller:

```
public static <T extends Shape> T draw2(T t) {
    t.draw();
    return t;
}
```

This makes a difference in situations when a subclass defines new methods on top of the base class. For example, if `Circle` defined

```
double radius() { return r;}
```

you could do the following:

```
double r = RenderEngine.draw1(c).radius();
```

This would be impossible with an implementation returning `Shape`.

**Note:** The above is to demonstrate the differences, not to suggest that the new implementation is more desirable than the original one.

Comment: public static void drawAll1(Shape... shapes) {
        for (Shape s : shapes) {
            draw1(s);
        }
    }

    public static void drawAll2(Shape... shapes) {
        for (Shape s : shapes) {
            draw2(s);
        }
    }

Comment: @ElliotDuan What are you trying to ask with this code fragment in your comment?

Comment: Do you think drawAll2() has better performance than drawAll1()? Sorry about the bad formatting.

Comment: @ElliotDuan There is no performance difference, because the two fragments will be translated to identical bytecode due to type erasure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I believe there's no difference between the two implementations.

Answer (score -1):

draw2 will do the same thing as draw for things that are already shapes.  But when it says `T extends Shape`, it allows it to take in a parameter that is not a shape.  At that point, it will allow it to use the `draw` method without crashing, whether or not it's a shape, it just might not draw anything.